# jquery ui autocomplete input element need to show all values when mouse over and focused

Tags: jquery

Demo :http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
I implemented above functionality in my site , client requirement is , input element will be shown all values when mouse hover and focused on input element .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to set `minLength: 0` on initialization of autocomplete and then create a `focus` listener on input field which calls `search` of the autocomplete plugin :) .

Magic code :)

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 0
});

$("#tags").focus(function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete( "search", "" ); 
});
```

You can change the `focus`listener to any event you want (and jQuery supports). Have a look at the event section of the [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). The second parameter of the search method specifies the search string. If its empty, autocomplete shows the whole list. This is also perfectly documented at the [JQuery UI Autocomplete API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search).

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dQXS/) with an example.

Comment: you can use `.focus(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == "") {
                        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
                    }
                })` too